# WCF ProtectionLevel

Tags: c#, wcf

If I apply ProtectionLevel as attribute of the service contract :

```
  [ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign)]
  public interface IService
   {
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData1(long token);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData2(long token);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData3(long token);

   }
```

will it be applied to all the methods? I mean, all my methods will be signed an encrypted?

Which is the difference of using MessageContract attributes on each method? (independently of granularity, in this case my goal is secure all my methods)

I know that working with MessageContract will have the restriction to return [MessageContract] marked class and also use [MessageContract] class as parameter.
Can I get the same result using primitive types and encrypting all the parameters and returns for my methods using the attribute at Interface level?

I'm planning to use wsHttpBinding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the ProtectionLevel is set at the interface level it applies to all OperationContracts and MessageContracts.

The hierarchy is as follows. Attributes at the same level are peers.

1. ServiceContractAttribute
2. OperationContractAttribute
3. MessageContractAttribute ,FaultContractAttribute
4. MessageHeaderAttribute, MessageBodyMemberAttribute

Setting the ProtectionLevel on the topmost sets the level for all below it. If the ProtectionLevel is set to a different value at a lower level, all below that level in the hierarchy will now be reset to the new level

Applying ProtectionLevel at each MessageContract level is for granular control

```
public class Record
{
   [MessageHeader(ProtectionLevel=None)] public int recordID;
   [MessageHeader(ProtectionLevel=EncryptAndSign)] public string SSN;
   [MessageBodyMember(ProtectionLevel=None)] public string comments;
   [MessageBodyMember(ProtectionLevel=EncryptAndSign)] public string history;
}
```

For message headers, the protection level is determined individually for each header.

For message body parts, the protection level of the body is determined by the highest ProtectionLevel property setting of all the body parts.

Using MessageContracts would be advisable for the below reasons

**Advantages of using MessageContracts**

- It is especially useful for SOAP based communication
- Control over the structure of a SOAP message Control over its contents.
- Control security issues at the level of the message or message part
- Interoperability(say communication between .net or java / client or
  services)

  ```
  [MessageContract]
  public class Record
  {
    [MessageHeader(Name="ID")] public int personID;
    [MessageBodyMember(Order=1)] public string comments;
  }
  ```

For security features to work, you must properly ***configure the binding and behaviors in the config or through code***.

Below shows a typical message security binding using wsHttpBinding

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingMessageSecurity">
      <security mode="message">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The above would change based on your security requirements.

**No Message Contracts**

You can configure the WCF service without Message Contracts. Implementing security would  work fine without Message Contracts.

Below is a typical example

Service Contract which has a method which returns a string (primitive datatype)

```
[ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign)]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    string Register();
}
```

Here is the binding

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"  sendTimeout="10.00:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

And here is the encrypted response (only body for brevity)

```
<s:Body u:Id="_0">
<e:EncryptedData Id="_1" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#uuid-fab89344-49bb-4b84-a7ea-02bad97b9142-6"/>
    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
  </KeyInfo>
  <e:CipherData>
    <e:CipherValue>BFlxwcK/QcXFlGUWNoE+LAOSizI1BEFKHlpDdHvby9PRwPTQFRztn+1pWmz8S0UgKzM/Puqud3N0G1tb/xcLsdNyIqgvQ68UjG+g5LGyqlbUEHa4+LaCWvW7ADN3eqoP+y1mhrN91ehIPpgYclrFHcIv/UDVCB+LLG4iMMikGqY=</e:CipherValue>
  </e:CipherData>
</e:EncryptedData>
```

So in order to implement security it is not necessary to have Message Contracts

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi dera thank you for your comments. As I mentioned, granularity is not main goal here. My big challenge is keep using the primitive type as parameter and return for my service methods, but when using [MessageContract] as credentials, other parameters and method return values should be converted also to [MessageContract]. If I don't use [MessageContract] which alternatives I have to get my communication between service and client secure?